# how to use or call java class in servlet and display the result to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am able to pass the searchterm in NewFile.jsp to HelloWorld servlet and display the result in wecome jsp.  I have another program wrote in the new java class.I do not know how to pass the searchterm to the java class. so as to run the program.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

NewFile.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title> My JSP page </title>
    </head> 
    <body>      
        <form method="post" action="HelloWorld">            
             Please enter a Keyword <br>
            <input type="text" name="searchTerm"size="20px">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">                        
        </form>     
    </body> 
</html>
```

welcomepage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%String X = (String)request.getAttribute("searchTerm");%>

 The search word is<%=X %>

<%-- welcom <%=request.getAttribute("searchTerm")%> --%>

</body>
</html>
```

servlet: HelloWorld.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet { 
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
  {
    doPost(request,response);

  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
          HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
      {


    // ..........reading the user input
    String searchTerm= request.getParameter("searchTerm");  
  request.setAttribute("searchTerm",searchTerm);
  request.getRequestDispatcher("welcomepage.jsp").forward(request, response);


  }  

  }
```

the other javascript: 
Myprogram.java

```
public class ParameterPy {

public static void main(String a[]){
try{

String searchTerm="google";

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Python27/python","D://program.py",""+searchTerm);
Process p = pb.start();

BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

System.out.println(".........start   process.........");  
String line = "";     
while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println("Python Output: " + line);
}
System.out.println("........end   process.......");


}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}
}
```

How do I link the variable searchterm in Myprogram.java with the variable in  HelloWorld.java (replace the "google" to the real time user input search term) since the  HelloWorld.java is a servlet can display to the jsp.

Comment: From where do you want to pass the variable searchterm to ParameterPy class. 1) from form in NewFile.jsp to ParameterPy class  2) or any jsp/servlet to ParameterPy class

Comment: i create a servlet called HelloWorld.java, I want to pass the variable from the servlet to java class

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:
**ParameterPy class**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class ParameterPy
{

    public static void myMethodName(String searchTerm)  
        {
            try
                {
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Python27/python", "D://program.py", ""+ searchTerm);
                    Process p = pb.start();

                    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    System.out.println(".........start   process.........");
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Python Output: " + line);
                        }
                    System.out.println("........end   process.......");

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
        }
}
```

**HelloWorld Servlet:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
      {
        doPost(request,response);

      }

      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
              HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
          {
        // ..........reading the user input

      String searchTerm= request.getParameter("searchTerm");  

      ParameterPy.myMethodName(searchTerm);//Call to java class method

      request.setAttribute("searchTerm",searchTerm);
      request.getRequestDispatcher("welcomepage.jsp").forward(request, response);

      }  
}
```

For your query in comments, right now you are printing the result of ParameterPy on `System.out`. In order to display the result on `jsp` webpage you need `JspWriter` object, i.e, `out`.
For this I have amended your logic as below to return result as `String`. This `String` result will be displayed on jsp page.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class ParameterPy
{
    public static String myMethodName2(String searchTerm)   
        {
            StringBuilder sb=null;
            try
                {
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Python27/python", "D://program.py", ""+ searchTerm);
                    Process p = pb.start();

                    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    sb=new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(".........start   process.........");
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sb.append("Python Output: " + line);
                        }
                    sb.append("........end   process.......");

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                return sb.toString();
        }
}
```

**JSP:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="stack.filter.ParameterPy"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    String searchTerm = request.getParameter("searchTerm");
    out.println(ParameterPy.myMethodName2(searchTerm));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I got it. btw, could i  ask u one question? If i want to display the ParameterPy result on the jsp page after i call "ParameterPy.myMethodName(searchTerm);//Call to java class method" in the serlvet.  how to get the result and display on the webpage?